# Bring Viewstate to bottom or disable Viewstate for crawlers

Tags: viewstate

I am optimizing website for making it SEO friendly. There are certain controls which need to have Viewstate. So, I cannot completely disable it. 

There are 2 ways through which I can achieve this.

 - Moving Viewstate data to bottom of the page.

 - Disable Viewstate only for crawlers.

Somewhere I had read that, changing contents for crawlers and normal user can affect SEO ranking. But not too much sure about the statement as this is going to affect ultimately a hidden field.

Moving Viewstate to bottom seems to take more resources then disabling the Viewstate for crawlers.

Please suggest what will be the best approach or any other option that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar question and ended up combining approaches so the ViewState is moved to the bottom only when the requesting agent is a crawler.  My question was closed because SEO is off topic for StackOverflow, but it might be helpful to read over it if you'd like to try this aproach:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328172/dealing-with-an-imperfect-viewstate-best-practices-move-to-the-bottom-disab

Best,
Stephen

Comment: Not sure on this. It might be treated as cloaking. So, I have reduced viewstate as much as possible.